# Python - converting to list

Tags: python, string, list, split

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

webpage = requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com/").text, "html.parser")
for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"): 
articles = story_heading.text.replace('\n', '').replace('  ', '')
print (articles)
```

There is my code, it prints out a list of all the article titles on the website. I get strings:

> Looking Back: 1980 | Funny, but Not Fit to Print
>
> Brooklyn Studio With Room for Family and a Dog
>
> Search for Homes for Sale or Rent
>
> Sell Your Home

So, I want to convert this to a list = ['Search for Homes for Sale or Rent', 'Sell Your Home', ...], witch will allow me to make some other manipulations like random.choice etc.
I tried:

```
alist = articles.split("\n")
print (alist)
```

> ['Looking Back: 1980 | Funny, but Not Fit to Print']
>
> ['Brooklyn Studio With Room for Family and a Dog']
>
> ['Search for Homes for Sale or Rent']
>
> ['Sell Your Home']

It is not a list that I need. I'm stuck. Can you please help me with this part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constantly overwriting `articles` with the next value in your list. What you want to do instead is make `articles` a list, and just `append` in each iteration:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

webpage = requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com/").text, "html.parser")
articles = []
for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"): 
    articles.append(story_heading.text.replace('\n', '').replace('  ', ''))
print (articles)
```

The output is huge, so this is a small sample of what it looks like:

```
['Global Deal Reached to Curb Chemical That Warms Planet', 'Accord Could Push A/C Out of Sweltering India’s Reach ',....]
```

Furthermore, you only need to strip spaces in each iteration. You don't need to do those replacements. So, you can do this with your `story_heading.text` instead:

```
articles.append(story_heading.text.strip())
```

Which, can now give you a final solution looking like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

webpage = requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com/").text, "html.parser")
articles = [story_heading.text.strip() for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading")]
print (articles)
```